# Can I deploy Windows Server Essentials 2019 in a larger domain?

Tags: windows-server-essentials, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server domain with over 10 servers, 60 desktops and 70 users. The domain controllers are running Windows Server 2012 R2. Now we need to add a few new servers for development purposes, and we are evaluating Windows Server 2019 in both Essentials and Standard editions. I am aware of the limitations of Essentials regarding a maximum of 25 users and 50 devices, but neither Microsoft now the resellers I have talked to have been able to explain how these limitations apply. For example: my domain has more than 25 users and 50 devices, but these new servers will not be accessed by more than perhaps 2 or 3 users and 6 or 7 devices, as they will be used as test and database servers in a development lab. Can I do this with Essentials?

In other words, how does Essentials "check" whether its environment meets the limitations or not? Will it contact the domain controllers to obtain the total number of machines and users in the domain and fail to install if the maximums are exceeded, or will it simply monitor how many simultaneous connections there are?

Comment: I believe the 25 users/50 devices refers to if Windows Server Essentials is deployed as a domain controller in its own Active Directory domain.

Answer (score -1):

Use Standard or Datacenter.

Dev test environments should be using the same software as production. That concerns exist about the [feature set of an Essentials edition](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Windows_Server_2016_Editions_comparison) is reason not to use it. Presumably you still want Hyper-V and 2 guest VOSEs for testing, the app on one and the domain controller on another.

An evaluation install may be appropriate for a dev test environment. When that expires, good excuse to destroy it and test bare metal restore procedures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you are not really addressing my question. I am aware of how to set up a test environment. My concern, as stated by the OP, is whether an Essentials server will work in a larger domain.